# calculating subsets of a matrix (L=40X40)

Tags: matrix, memory, subset

I need to calculate all $k$-possible subsets$(k:1,L)$ of matrix with size $L$. I am using subset function as following,

```
L = 10;
Do[
   t = L!/(k! (L - k)!);
   tstmat = RandomReal[L, {L, L}];
   config = Subsets[Range[Length@tstmat], {k}];
   Print[{k, t}]
   , 
   {k, 1, L}
];
```

this is working fine up to $L=24$, but for big sizes I am running into memory issues,

### L  |   mem

### 25 | 2.152 G

### 26 | 3.600 G

### 27 | 6.470 G

### 28 | 12.418 G

### 29 | 23.641 G

I am assuming the huge memory is related to part of code where it's calculating the different subsets and keeps all of different configuration, for example for size `L=30` and `L=40` this becomes on the order of `10^9` and `10^12` sub-lists, respectively. Is there any way to decrease the memory, for example by keeping subsets once at a time? Or maybe is there any other function in Mathematica to calculate the all possible subsets?

Comment: @Arnoud Buzing:  Do you need to store all these subsets, or can you perform your test or processing of them individually and reject (not store) elements that are not needed?

Comment: See for example http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/NextKSubset.html . But there are other questions on this site about this problem. Search for them!

Comment: Hi Arnould,  I don't need to store all the subsets but I need to do calculation on each element of subset where I construct the new sub-matrices with eliminating the rows and columns related to the each sub-list and calculate the determinant and move to the next subset. So in practice I need to calculate the det of number of matrices equal to the number of all subsets with max size(L!)/(k!*(L-k)!).

Comment: At the end of the Do loop config={Range @L},  the code seems not compute anything else on the sublists

Comment: @penguin77: I have not iclude that part of the code, but this is waht it looks like,Do[Prob1 = 
Det[tstmat[[#, #]]] & /@ 
    Subsets[Range[Length@tstmat], {k}];
  Sh1 = -Prob1.Log[Prob1] + Sh1, {k, 1, L}];

Comment: @ David G. Stork:   I don't need to store all the subsets but I need to do calculation on each element of subset where I construct the new sub-matrices with eliminating the rows and columns related to the each sub-list and calculate the determinant and move to the next subset. So in practice I need to calculate the det of number of matrices equal to the number of all subsets with max size(L!)/(k!*(L-k)!).

Comment: @ belisarius :Thanks for replying, I have looked in the page and in fact i am trying to use combinatoria', please check the bottom of the page for psudo code that I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take out of `Do` any evaluation that need to be done only once and make sure to clear variables between successive runs.

```
Clear[L, LL, k, config]
L = 50; LL = L!;  
Do[t = LL/(k! (L - k)!); Print[{k, t}], {k, 1, L}]
```

As an alternative for using  `Do` you may consider

```
 {Range @ L, Table[k! (L - k)!, {k, 1, L}]  // L!/# &} // Thread
```

The result of config, when `Do` reaches end is

```
config=Subsets[Range[Length@RandomReal[L, {L, L}]],{L}]
```

therefore it can be calculated separately

Comment: Hi'  Thanks for suggesting the method, I have run the method and using {Range @ L, Table[k! (L - k)!, {k, 1, L}]  // L!/# &} // Thread, it actually increases the memory that we need, here is the new scaling [L=25, mem=4.84] compare it with the original scaling, I would say that the main part that it takes a lot of memory is subsets, I am looking for some function to avoid to keep all subset list in subset function and take each one and do some calculation(which I have not written in above code)and move to the next subset.

Comment: @setareh, you are right,  I have noticed Subsets makes some troubles. Memory use for other code is minimal.  Sorry did not first understand your intention for "real code" involving subsets.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick kludge to do what you're after. You'd probably want to properly modularize it for actual code use (i.e., not carrying around globals) or better yet incorporate the `NextKSubset` and your code into a `Nest`, `NestList`, `Fold` or `FoldList` as appropriate:

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]];

fss[lst_, siz_] := (tmp1 = stop = Take[lst, siz]; 
   nss := (tmp = Combinatorica`NextKSubset[lst, tmp1]; tmp1 = tmp; 
     If[tmp === stop, {}, tmp]); tmp1);
```

Use:

```
(* get first subset of some range of some size *)
fss[Range@40,10]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)

(* get subsequent 10 subsets *)
Table[nss, {10}]
(*
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12}, {1,
   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14}, {1, 
  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16}, {1, 2,
   3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 17}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 18}, {1, 2, 
  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20}}
*)
```

The use of the `Block` in setting up `Combinatorica` avoids clashes with built-ins, and necessitates the fully qualified name use.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I started to using the function you have defined, so this is psudo code for L=4 and k=2, so,                           Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]];
L = 4;
KSubsets[Range@L, 2]
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}
 fss[lst_, siz_] := (tmp1 = stop = Take[lst, siz];
   nss := (tmp = Combinatorica`NextKSubset[lst, tmp1]; tmp1 = tmp;
     If[tmp === stop, {}, tmp]); tmp1);

 tstmat = RandomInteger[L, {L, L}];
k = 2;
t = L!/(k! (L - k)!);
 config = Table[nss, {5}]
 {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}

Comment: I suppose this function will create a big list as k increases. So is there a way to just access the nth element of subsets, to keep the usage of memory as low as possible? For example I would like to access the first element {1,2} and build new matrix such as Prob1 = Det[tstmat[[#, #]]] & /@{1,2}+Prob1 and then move to the second element and similarly calculate Prob1 = Det[tstmat[[#, #]]] & /@{1,3}+Prob1 and so on ....

Comment: @setareh that is precisely what this does.  One element of subsets at time. No intermediate lists are used.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for replying and sharing comments for this post, considering all comments I came up with my own solution, see the code below,

```
    ClearAll[tsmat, lst, k, i, t, L, s];
    L = 20;
    tstmat = RandomInteger[L, {L, L}];
    lst = Range@L;
    Do[t = L!/(k! (L - k)!);
          Print[{k, t}];
      s = Range[k];
        Do[
       s = NextKSubset[lst, s], {i, 1, t}];
    , {k, 1, L}];
```

and here is new scaling for memory,

```
 L | mem
25 | 1.399 G
26 | 2.008 G
27 | 3.735 G
28 | 8.785 G
```

and the time scaling also is much faster than before(L=28,time=2 min!). But still I would like to decrease the memory as much as possible to run for bigger L. As a beginner in Mathematica I don't know that much of optimizing code, I would greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a better way using `NthSubset` function available in `Combinatoria` package, here is the code,

```
     << Combinatorica`;
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]];                                                  ClearAll[tsmat, k, L, s, i];
L = 4;
tstmat = RandomInteger[L, {L, L}];
lst = Range@L;
Do[
 config = NthSubset[i, lst];
 Print[{i, config}], {i, 1, 2^L - 1}]
```

The memory is dramatically lower than previous case, it almost stays around 703 MB up to size L=30!