# It is possible to calculate a two vector integral

Tags: vector-calculus, calculus-and-analysis

I have this problem:
calculate the integral of:

```
-1+Sqrt[2*d+1]
```

with `d` being a distance of two points in a 60$\times$60 box (inside or on the boundaries).

I know nothing of *Mathematica*.

I realize who to define functions with two variables and then calculate the integral in a specific interval for each variable (in this case [0,60]). But I do not know how to define a function with two vectors and then calculate the integral giving interval for each vector.

Well instead of using two vectors I can use 4 variables. The function seams to be defined correctly, but when I Integrate I don't get a result.

```
f[x_, y_, z_, w_] := Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + (z - w)^2]
f[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

(* Sqrt[2] *)

```
h[x_, y_, z_, w_] := -1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*f[x, y, z, w]]
h[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

(*  -1 + Sqrt[1 + 2 Sqrt[2]] *)

```
Integrate[
h[x, y, z, w], {x, 0, 60}, {y, 0, 60}, {z, 0, 60}, {w, 0, 60}]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am stuck.

Thanks in advance
John

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SE! Please provide a minimal example of what you tried so far, using proper formatting (note the "help"-menu on the top of this site). Did you already take a look at the *Mathematica* online documentation (at all)?

Comment: take a stab at writing some mathematica code. I can't tell where you are stuck, and the problem isn't clearly posed.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* this is what you're seeking:

$\int _0^{60}\int _0^{60}\int _0^{60}\int _0^{60}\left(-1+\sqrt{2
   \sqrt{(\text{ax}-\text{bx})^2+(\text{ay}-\text{by})^2}+1}\right) d\text{by}\ d\text{bx}\ d\text{ay}\ d\text{ax}$

```
NIntegrate[
  -1 + Sqrt[2 Sqrt[(ax - bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2] + 1], 
  {ax, 0, 60}, {ay, 0, 60}, {bx, 0, 60}, {by, 0, 60}] // Quiet
```

(* 
$8.70647\times 10^7$
*)

Comment: However, the error estimate of this integral is quite huge...

Comment: @Jinxed  Huge... and yet correct.  I suspect you've mis-stated your problem.  Please revisit your problem *carefully*.  Perhaps you want to compute an *average*... but nobody can tell from your question.

Comment: Me? Are you sure?

Comment: I suppose you meant the OP, not me.

Comment: @Jinxed David has been exercising this for a while http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79334/193 :)

Comment: @belisarius: A wee bit odd. ;)

Comment: You can break that into nested 2d integrals and it converges without errors/warnings.  ( Essentially the same result `8.70659*10^7` )

Comment: yes this seams wright, but:
- why NIntegrate?
- when I copy/paste the code I dont get a result
- 8.7... * 10^7 cannot be the result. The Integrate give the mean of a weighted distance between two points in a 60x60 rectangle, based on a weighted function. The max weighted distance (from (0,0) to (60,60)) is 12.0654363679431.

Comment: `NIntegrate[
 h[x, y, z, w], {x, 0, 60}, {y, 0, 60}, {z, 0, 60}, {w, 0, 60}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 20]` seems to yield the same result without error warning…?